# App is not showing in full screen when orientation change in middle of app in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

App is working fine either in landscape or in portrait mode and layout is perfect also.But in middle of app when I change orientation from landscape to to portrait or vice versa, and then navigate to back or push to another VC, app is showing in half are of screen.I am not using auto layout, using code(Objective C).

```
-(void)setframeforLandScape{
    CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
    CGFloat screenWidth = screenRect.size.width;
    CGFloat screenHeight = screenRect.size.height;

    CGFloat yoffset=0.0;
    CGFloat xoffset=0.0;
    CGRect fram =_headerView.frame;
    fram.origin.x=0;
    yoffset=fram.origin.y+fram.size.height;

    fram=_titleView.frame;
    fram.size.width=screenWidth/2-50;
    fram.origin.x=0;
    fram.origin.y=_headerView.frame.origin.y+_headerView.frame.size.height;
    _titleView.frame=fram;
    yoffset=fram.origin.y+fram.size.height;

    fram=carousel.frame;
    fram.origin.y=_headerView.frame.origin.y+_headerView.frame.size.height;
    fram.size.width=screenWidth/2-50;
    if(IDIOM==IPAD){
        fram.size.height=400;
    }
    fram.origin.x=0;
    carousel.frame=fram;
    yoffset=fram.origin.y+fram.size.height;

    fram=_rateview.frame;
    fram.origin.x=0;
    fram.size.width=screenWidth/2-50;

    fram.origin.y = yoffset-fram.size.height-10;
    _rateview.frame=fram;

    fram=detailView.frame;
    fram.size.width=screenWidth/2+50;
    if(IDIOM==IPAD){
        fram.size.height=400;
    }
    fram.origin.x=screenWidth/2-50;

    fram.origin.y=_headerView.frame.size.height+_headerView.frame.origin.y;
    detailView.frame=fram;
    NSLog(@"detail:%f",detailView.frame.size.width);
    if(IDIOM==IPAD){
        mailButton.frame=CGRectMake(screenWidth/2-150, 0, 300, 80);

        _footerview.frame=CGRectMake(0, screenHeight-100, screenWidth, 100);
    }else{
        _footerview.frame=CGRectMake(0, screenHeight-50, screenWidth, 50);

    }
}
```

---

```
-(void)setFrame{
    CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
    CGFloat screenWidth = screenRect.size.width;
    CGFloat screenHeight = screenRect.size.height;
    CGFloat yoffset=0.0;
    CGRect fram =_headerView.frame;
    fram.origin.x=0;
    fram.size.width=screenWidth;
    yoffset=fram.origin.y+fram.size.height;

    fram=_titleView.frame;
    fram.size.width=screenWidth;
    fram.origin.x=0;
    fram.origin.y=_headerView.frame.origin.y+_headerView.frame.size.height;
    _titleView.frame=fram;
    yoffset=fram.origin.y+fram.size.height;

    fram=carousel.frame;
    fram.origin.x=0;
    fram.origin.y=_headerView.frame.origin.y+_headerView.frame.size.height;
    fram.size.width=screenWidth;
    if(IDIOM==IPAD){
        fram.size.height=400;
    }
    carousel.frame=fram;

    yoffset=fram.origin.y+fram.size.height;

    fram=_rateview.frame;
    fram.origin.x=0;
    fram.size.width=screenWidth;
    fram.origin.y = yoffset-fram.size.height;
    _rateview.frame=fram;


    fram=detailView.frame;
    fram.origin.x=0;
    fram.size.width=screenWidth;
    fram.origin.y=yoffset;
    if(IDIOM==IPAD){
        fram.size.height=350;
    }
    detailView.frame=fram;

    if(IDIOM==IPAD){
        mailButton.frame=CGRectMake(screenWidth/2-150, 0, 300, 80);

        _footerview.frame=CGRectMake(0, screenHeight-100, screenWidth, 100);
    }else{
        _footerview.frame=CGRectMake(0, screenHeight-50, screenWidth, 50);

    }
}
```

Comment: can you show your tried code

Comment: Now you can see.

Comment: Resetting your views in code for orientation change is not a very good practice. I would highly recommend to use constraints and size classes to achieve the desired effect. Once you get the hang of it, it will make your life a lot easier. You can look up different tutorials for that. They are easily available on the Internet.

Comment: As I have checked, rootviewcontroller hide the half of screen in this case.